# Bank negligence, checkings account compromised by id thief and bank on purpose holds me responsible to further my debt with interest

Tags: united-states, fraud, consumer-protection, negligence, identity-theft

I been a victim of id theft. On the same day that there were two fake checks deposited that were bounced, money was withdrawn physically within a branch of the bank, that day and another time four days later. The endorsement signatures of the checks that bounced were not even close to my signature, neither was the signature of the withdraw slip.

Now to make matters worse the bank decides to close my credit card. Their investigation on my claims for those transactions was just a bunch of runarounds, to waste time and give false hope.

Now in my credit report it says that I disagree with the closing of my credit card within that same institution, when I have never spoken to them about my credit card, simply about the transactions that took place in their branch where a impostor was able to walk away (twice) with money.

It just could not be more obvious that the bank who is paying 3 billion in civil lawsuit is desperate to make something from the crime that I am going through. So it is not just blame the victim, is definitely go at the victim together with the thief as if it was a act of collaboration fueled by greed.

They just make it harder on me to resolve this situation, having me call all types of departments in various continents or the people in branches trying to just give me the same numbers to call as the branch managers are not " qualified to deal with id theft." Their actions are malevolent as they are misleading, a person impersonating me, walks in twice and circumvents their said "security protocols" since they had commercial campaigns saying they've changed and want to regain the trust of the customer

Besides making complaints to federal organizations, and disputing with the bureaus, what else can be done?

the operation of this bank is arrogant, even after their previous CEO has been ordered to pay millions of dollars and kept away from banking, this bank has only gotten worse in customer service and has no intention of regaining my trust as a customer of 10+ years with the institution.

What kind of lawyer can help resolve this situation besides a consumer rights lawyer, as my credit score is being put on the line, but also my immediate financial well being and the reputation that I have of being able to make payments on time as the money that was in my checkings is now in the negative

Answer (score 0):

### You can do [these things](https://www.identitytheft.gov/know-your-rights)

Who is responsible for the losses (you or your bank) depends on how they happened and when you told the bank about them. For example, for the withdrawals on your cheque account, the bank is responsible *if* you told them they were fraudulent within 60 days of receiving your statement; if not, then you are responsible.

Comment: yep i did the day after then after about 15 busines days and bunch of calls I was given a timeline that never materialized then they closed my credit card and said that i disputed it when i never talked to them about my credit card since it all had to do with checkings the id thief has only applied for credit cards but not hacked any card i have with the bank